# How to display & design list of list in rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, report, rdlc

Requirement :

I want to design my rdlc as follows for a MVC project: 
I have a main List and in that few properties and a list as well.

```
public class ServiceWiseDetailEntity
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }


    public string ServiceName { get; set; }


    public List<SessionDetailEntity> SessionDetails { get; set; }

    public string LabelName { get; set; }
}
```

This needs to be shown in rdlc report as :

Heading : `[ServiceDetails.Count] Details for [ServiceName]`

A table with `List<ServiceDetails>`

[image: sample rdlc table example]

So from the heading to table will be repeated as many times as the data present in the main List `List<ServiceWiseDetailEntity>`

Problem Statement :

1. How to design the rdlc report in order to achieve above requirement.
2. I am confused as to how to represent my data in DataSet since it is not coming from database, manually added to Dataset.

For now I am using relations in DataSet where my `ServiceDetails` is being referenced with another table `ServiceWiseDetailEntity` both are related using `ServiceId`, Can below relation help me with navigation to objects?

[image]

Can Anybody help with this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a flat contract in your case `List<SessionDetailEntity> SessionDetails` will be only used.
There is no need to use the list in another class.

Just add all the extra properties  in to `SessionDetailEntity` class only.

Follow the Steps :

1. You can add a list in rdlc design.
2. Add group on the list of rdlc design.
3. Use the property you want to group your data by - which will be your heading.
4. After that add a table and expressions to display data.

   It will repeat your data as you explained.

You can also refer to following youtube video which explains about grouping :

[Youtube - Adding Group & Using a List Item to Display Details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8EidVXasYg)